# Catalyst dispatchers (not using them)

Tags: perl, catalyst

Our site is written in plain Perl (and our codebase is rather big).

We are going to refactor it.

Catalyst uses "method dispatchers" (like ":Path"). But our site is written with a large number of our custom written dispatchers.

My question: If we switch to Catalyst, will we able to use our custom method dispatchers, rather than rewrite all in the Catalyst way? (possibly switching to Catalyst way later ("incrementally"))

So, is it worth for our big site to refactor it with Catalyst?

I am a long time Perl programmer, but Catalyst novice.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a site where part of it was Catalyst, along with lots of CGI scripts and mod_perl handlers. We did not use Plack (the project was started before Plack was introduced). We deployed all of our code (CGI, mod_perl handlers and Catalyst) using Apache. The first level of dispatching is done in Apache httpd's configuration, using the Location directive, where requests would be handled by CGI, mod_perl or Catalyst based on their URLs.

For example, to run the CGI scripts:

```
ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/home/httpd/cgi-bin/"
```

And on top of that, to run Catalyst for URLs matching "/myapp":

```
<Location /myapp>
    SetHandler          modperl
    PerlResponseHandler MyApp
</Location>
```

It is a little oversimplified. Please look at http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Catalyst-Manual-5.9009/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Deployment/Apache/mod_perl.pod as that is very much how we deployed our Catalyst portion of our application.

Just to give you a little more details. Catalyst was introduced when we already had lots of code which is a little similar to your situation. And we didn't want to rewrite everything in Catalyst because of time constraints.

To answer your question:
Yes, you can switch to Catalyst (even incrementally) and still be able to use the existing custom method dispatchers.

Comment: We use dispatchers hard-coded in our (F)CGI scripts. Server dispatch configuration is not very complex. How to connect between our old CGI scripts and new Catalyst code? You have said that this is possible but not explained how to do it

Comment: I've added a simplified example of how our application was configured in Apache httpd to handle requests to be handled by Catalyst and CGI. I think once a request goes to your CGI space, you'd have no problem using the old dispatchers.

Comment: We didn't really "connect" our Catalyst code and CGI scripts directly. A lot of functionalities needed in Catalyst space were refactored into libraries that can be used by both Catalyst and CGI code.

Comment: My question is yet unanswered: How to use Catalyst together with our custom written dispatchers in (F)CGI (or rather in our custom written .pm modules used by our (F)CGI)?

Comment: Your custom .pm modules can be used like any other Perl modules. You can load them up using 'use' or 'require'. Of course you have to put the path to those modules in your @INC, possibly by using 'use lib' in your Catalyst script.

Comment: My question was not whether I can access our custom modules with @INC (it is obviously possible), but if Catalyst path system can be (ab)used together with our custom written dispatchers (even despite the fact that Catalyst has its own path system)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to replace Catalyst's dispatcher with your custom dispatcher. A simple diagram would have helped. I'm afraid that defeats the purpose of using Catalyst. However you can always define a controller and base on that controller's path, dispatch using your own dispatcher as you have the request's path and params for your disposal.